# Will time machine backup my whole Adobe CS apps?

Tags: applications, backup, time-machine, adobe

I wish to upgrade my OSX and am worried I lose my Adobe CS apps since they were issued by my (ex)college and i do not have the keys/seriel#'s

I didnt quite understand the answer given. Will a TM backup save all this apps/data so if my new osx gives me problems I can 'go back' and recover the previous osx and ALL my apps/data incl the Adobe stuff! ?

thanks D

Comment: Back up will backup every thing if told to.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not use applications you don't have licenses for.

Yes, time machine backs up all data. If you chose to reinstall the same OS X version on the same computer everything should be the same.

Please keep in mind, though, that adobe's creative suite (CS1) does not work on newer versions of OA X/macOS.

Comment: Thanks OA-
The college has the license and afaik its a group license so students can use it. I paid the college to have this use - i just hope they didnt screw me over on it :D
ok gtk its an all data backup  (y)
yes i have CS5 suite. 
thanks